# Java array issue

Tags: java, arrays

How would I go about creating an array of say 5 items and then after create an array for each item?.  I know how to create an array of 5 items but the problem I have is creating an array for each one after.  Im assuming I would need 5 arrays since there's 5 items.

```
 int gas = 0;
 int food = 0;
 int clothes = 0;
 int entertainment = 0;
 int electricity = 0;
 int[] budget = new int[4];
 budget[0] = gas;
 budget[1] = food;
 budget[2] = clothes;
 budget[3] = entertainment;
 budget[4] = electricity;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, when you say "then after create an array for each item"? It really sounds like you want a `HashMap` of `ArrayList`s keyed by your items.

Comment: Why do you need an array for each item? Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? What does the array and the individual items represent?

Comment: What do you mean by an array for each item?  Are you saying an array for gas and an array for food...  Or are you saying you want to put the budget array into another array?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a 2-dimensional array holding types of amounts that are logically grouped together (I assume per month) it would be better to define a data-holder class so that you can access the amounts using their name instead of an error-prone index.

For example (minus the getters and setters):

```
public class Budget {
    public int gas = 0;
    public int food = 0;
    public int clothes = 0;
    public int entertainment = 0;
    public int electricity = 0;
};

// ....
Budget[] months = new Budget[12];

budget[0].gas = gasCosts;
budget[0].food = foodCosts;
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to create a 2D array? Each element in the budget array is another array?

You'd use a loop.

```
int[] budget = new int[5]; //There are 5 elements to be stored in budget, not 4
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
     budget[y] = new int[5];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `int[][] budget = new int[5][];`

Comment: You might be right - I haven't done that in Java for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a matrix.

```
int[][] budget = new int[4][4];
```

In the first index you keep the budget and in the second index the five (in the case above) budget items.
When you have a matrix [x][y] you have x+1 arrays each of wich with y+1 elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 elements in the array.

```
    int[] budget = new int[5];
    budget[0] = gas;
    budget[1] = food;
    budget[2] = clothes;
    budget[3] = entertainment;
    budget[4] = electricity;
```

You need 2-dimensional array, which is basically an array of array. The 2D array is declared by 2 pairs of []. In the following example, each `budget` have 10 details.

```
    String[][] detail = new String[budget.length][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a 2d array that would be something like ...

```
int gas = 0;
int food = 1;
int clothes = 2;
int entertainment = 3;
int electricity = 4;
int maxEntries = 10;

int[][] myArray = new int[5][maxEntries];
```

This could be accessed via:

```
myArray[gas][entryNumber] = 6;
int value = myArray[gas][entryNumber];
```

But how inflexible this is? You have to know in advance how many entries there will be for each "category" or have code that checks a given array length when you're adding an item, creating an new array when you need a larger one (and copying the old data into it).

What you probably want at the very least is a `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> my2dArrayList = 
    new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
...
my2dArrayList.get(gas).add(someValue);
int myValue = my2dArrayList.get(gas).get(index);
```

Or a `HashMap` of `ArrayList`s you could access via the names of your categories:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> myMap = 
    new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
...
myMap.get("gas").add(someValue);
int myValue = myMap.get("gas").get(index);
```